# Variables inside formulas appearing with quotes

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to insert 2 variables into a formula. Altough they are appearing inside quotes.

```
fase1 = Cells(2, diffdate_ac + 4).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
prod1 = Cells(4, diffdate_ac + 4).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
```

Fase1 refers to AG2 and Prod1 to AG4.

```
Range("B3").Formula = "=SUM((SUMIFS(ben_quant,ben_dia,R[-1]C,ben_fase, " & fase1 & ",ben_linha," & prod1 & "))
```

It is part of the formula. " & fase 1 & " is giving me 'AG2', and " & prod 1 & " is returning 'AG4'. Yes, they are both inside quotes inside the formula as the image shows:

[image]

I want to remove those single quotes, because that way the formula is not referring to those cells.

The complete part of the code of this command

```
'Prints an array of dates
Dim startac2 As Long, finishac2 As Long
Dim datearray3 As Variant, y As Long

finishac2 = CLng(DateValue(lastac))
startac2 = CLng(DateValue(firstac))
    ReDim datearray3(finishac2 - startac2 + 1)

    For y = 0 To finishac2 - startac2
        datearray3(y) = startac2 + y
    Next

diffdate_ac = DateDiff("d", startac2, finishac2) + 1

wsPBen.Activate
Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(2, diffdate_ac + 1)).Value = datearray3
Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(2, diffdate_ac + 1)).NumberFormat = "d/m;@"
'

Range("A1").Value = "BENEFICIAMENTO: TINTURARIA LISO"
Range("A2").Value = "Data"
Range("A3").Value = "Produção"
Cells(2, diffdate_ac + 2).Value = "TOTAL"
Cells(2, diffdate_ac + 3).Value = "FASE"
Cells(4, diffdate_ac + 3).Value = "PRODUTO"
Cells(2, diffdate_ac + 4).Value = "TINGIR ALTA TEMP."
Cells(3, diffdate_ac + 4).Value = "TINGIR BAIXA TEMP."
Cells(4, diffdate_ac + 4).Value = "TINTO RAMADO"
Cells(5, diffdate_ac + 4).Value = "TINTO TUBULAR"


Dim fase1 As String
Dim fase2 As String
Dim prod1 As String
Dim prod2 As String

fase1 = Cells(2, diffdate_ac + 4).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
fase2 = Cells(3, diffdate_ac + 4).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
prod1 = Cells(4, diffdate_ac + 4).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
prod2 = Cells(5, diffdate_ac + 4).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)


Range("B3").formula = "=SUM((SUMIFS(ben_quant,ben_dia,R[-1]C,ben_fase," & fase1 & ",ben_linha," & prod1 & ")),(SUMIFS(ben_quant,ben_dia,R[-1]C,ben_fase," & fase1 & ",ben_linha," & prod2 & ")),(SUMIFS(ben_quant,ben_dia,R[-1]C,ben_fase," & fase2 & ",ben_linha," & prod1 & ")),(SUMIFS(ben_quant,ben_dia,R[-1]C,ben_fase," & fase2 & ",ben_linha," & prod2 & ")))"
```

Comment: If you step through the code with the debugger, are the single quotes already present when setting fase1 and prod1?  And is there any intermediate code between the two fragments that alters fase1 and prod1 in any way?

Comment: what variable type are `fase1` and `prod1`? They should be declared as `String`.

Comment: The quotes are already present. Double quotes actually, I think my excel version (Portuguese) turns them into single quotes. There's no code between those lines. And both variables are declared as String. Can't figure out why that is happening.

Comment: The whole line Range `("B3").Formula = "=SUM((SUMIFS(ben_quant,ben_dia,R[-1]C,ben_fase, " & fase1 & ",ben_linha," & prod1 & ")),(SUMIFS(ben_quant,ben_dia,R[-1]C,ben_fase," & fase1 & ",ben_linha," & prod2 & ")),(SUMIFS(ben_quant,ben_dia,R[-1]C,ben_fase," & fase2 & ",ben_linha," & prod1 & ")),(SUMIFS(ben_quant,ben_dia,R[-1]C,ben_fase," & fase2 & ",ben_linha," & prod2 & ")))"`

Comment: @mschlindwein: To be paranoid, please Dim an extra String, and assign the formula you're building up to that string.  Then step through the code with the debugger and tell us if the formula-in-a-string also has those quotes.

Comment: It probably wont make a difference, but you could try just taking the address (without setting row and column absolute to false) and the use `Replace` to remove the dollar sign. You could also assign it all to a string and remove the single quotes with `Replace`.

Comment: I created a msgBox with the string  and no quotes appeared this time. I don't know what to do with that though

Comment: I checked the debugger and the "string formula" has those quotes too.

Comment: @mschlindwein: I've added an 'answer' with a code sample; could you test that and see what happens?  I'm stumped actually by what's going on; the code in that sample works for me.

Comment: You are mixing R1C1 and A1 formula format in the offending line.  AFAIK, that is never valid.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: that was it; I added an R1C1 component to the code in my sample and all A1 style references got quoted - learned something new today!  I'd say make it an answer.

Comment: OK, I have added it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I read you correctly, this VBA line:

```
Range("B3").Formula = "=SUM((SUMIFS(ben_quant,ben_dia,R[-1]C,ben_fase, " & fase1 & ",ben_linha," & prod1 & "))"
```

Is trying to set this formula expression:

```
=SUM((SUMIFS(ben_quant,ben_dia,R[-1]C,ben_fase, AG2,ben_linha,AG4))
```

However, this is mixing R1C1 and A1 cell addressing in the same formula.  As far as I know, that is always invalid syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks OK to me...  Could you start a fresh Excel workbook, go to the VBA editor, and paste the following code in a new module?

```
Sub x()
  Dim cellAddress As String
  cellAddress = Cells(1, 1).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
  Dim formula As String
  formula = "=SUMIFS(B1:B4,C1:C4," & cellAddress & ")"
  Call MsgBox(formula)
  Range("A2").formula = formula
End Sub
```

After this, run it and tell us if the prompt shows any quotes in the formula, and tell us what's in cell A2 afterwards.

Comment: No, no! That is working fine, that'd be my solution. I have added the complete part of the code on the OP.

Comment: If the code above works for you, but your own code you posted does not, then I'm out of options since they use the exact same syntax?  Are you really sure there's no difference in my and your code set-up and/or did you thoroughly debug both code sets to check how they behave?

Comment: That's really weird because both our codes work the same way when I debug them. When I put them in the same module in my current worksheet, your code returns the correct value without quotes, while mine not. I'll keep trying to find a solution, asap I'll share it.

Comment: As RBarryYoung suggested, it's caused by mixing R1C1 style referencing with A1 type referencing; see his newer answer for the details.

Answer (score 1):

I'd simply replace the quotes with nothing:

```
Range("B3").Formula = "=SUM((SUMIFS(ben_quant,ben_dia,R[-1]C,ben_fase," & fase1 & ",ben_linha," & prod1 & ")),(SUMIFS(ben_quant,ben_dia,R[-1]C,ben_fase," & fase1 & ",ben_linha," & prod2 & ")),(SUMIFS(ben_quant,ben_dia,R[-1]C,ben_fase," & fase2 & ",ben_linha," & prod1 & ")),(SUMIFS(ben_quant,ben_dia,R[-1]C,ben_fase," & fase2 & ",ben_linha," & prod2 & ")))"
Range("B3").Formula = Replace(Range("B3").Formula, "'", "")
```

Comment: That is working! I think the problem was with the SUM((SUMIFS formula. I tried using just SUMIF or just SUM and it was working. Thanks